# What is the complexity of these two string based algorithms?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I have written these two algorithms to check a string for duplicate characters (ABBC, AAAC). The first uses the hashset data structure, whilst the second relies purely on iteration.

**Algorithm 1**

```
String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxxyz";

public boolean isUnique(String s) {

        Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet<Character>();

        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
            if(charSet.contains(s.charAt(i))) {
                return false;   
            } 
            charSet.add(s.charAt(i));
        }   
        return true;
}
```

**Algorithm 2**

```
String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxxyz";

public boolean isUnique2(String s) {

        for(int i=0; i<s.length()-1; i++) {
            for(int j = i+1; j<s.length(); j++) {
                if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
}
```

My thoughts are that the first algorithm is O(N), and the second algorithm is O(N^2). When i run execution time tests on my (possibly unreliable) laptop, the average speed for the first algorithm is 2020ns, whilst the second algorithm is 995ns. This goes against my calculation of the algorithms complexity, could anybody advise me?

Comment: @zubergu: No! `HashSet`s work differently.

Comment: @fabian I just realized the HashSet part :)

Comment: Understand that performance at runtime cannot be gleaned from big O notation alone.

Comment: How are you measuring execution time? Are you just testing how long it takes for the whole executable to run, or just the method body? If it's the former, you're probably not going to notice a big difference with such a small dataset. Either way, time complexity and runtime are two different things. Time complexity assumes nothing about what you're actually running the code on, which in this case is the jvm, and that introduces some initial overhead.

Comment: Try it with a string that has more than 1 million characters and see what you get.

Comment: @MadConan just the method body.

Comment: @MadConan Surely after the first 26 characters there would be a duplicate character guaranteed? isnt a million characters unnecessary?

Comment: @DomShahbazi OK a million is a stretch.  But you could use a few thousand unicode chars.

Comment: @Dom: time complexity does not represent actual running time of an algorithm. It is used to measures the relative performance of two algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using O() notation you ignore constants, which means that O(n) == (10^10*n). so while O(n^2)>O(n) is true asymptotically, its not necessarily true for smaller values of n.
in your case imagine that maybe resizing the array behind the hashset could be more time consuming than iterating the input.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the charAt method runs in O(1) time, the first algorithm is O(N) and the second is O(N^2). A linear time algorithm is not supposed to be faster than a quadratic algorithm for all inputs. It will be faster than the quadratic one after a certain N (which could possibly be in the millions).

for example:

```
void funcA(int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++){
            int k = i + j;
        }
    }
}


void funcB(int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            int k = i + j;
        }
    }
}
```

even though funcA is linear and funcB is quadratic, it is easy to see that funcB will be faster than funcA for n < 10000. In your case the hashSet requires time to compute the hash and so may be slower for inputs of a certain size.

Answer (score 1):

Micro benchmarking that you are doing can give very misleading info about algorithm complexities.

It's easy to "port" your algorithms to check for duplicates in, say, array of Integers.

Then I recommend testing performance on say, array of 10^7 elements and you will definitely see the difference.

This way you'd be able to confirm your initially correct estimation O(N) for hashset vs O(N^2) for the second "loop" version.

Comment: I shall try this now with a large array of integers, thankyou

Comment: try to initialize big enough array of ints with [pseudo-] random numbers first, and pass same input to one method under test after the other, measuring execution time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your test data, for example, if you limit yourself to English language characters (a-z), you are guaranteed to have a duplicate if string length > 26. In the specific example you provided the string `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxxyz"` is sorted and the duplicate element `x` is found towards the end. As such iterated array lookup is faster because there is overhead in building the `HashSet` as you continue to parse the String.

A better test would be to test this with randomly generated integer sequences of large sizes and with a large max value, e.g. `Long.MAX_VALUE`

Below is a test that disproves your assertion that array search is faster. Run it a few times and see for yourself. Or you could take averages from 1000 runs, etc:

```
public class FindDuplicatesTest {

  public static final String s = generateRandomString(100000);

  private static String generateRandomString(int numChars) {
    Random random = new Random();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < numChars; i++) {
      int codePoint = random.nextInt(65536);
      sb.append(Character.toChars(codePoint));
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public boolean isUnique(String s) {

    Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet<Character>();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      if (charSet.contains(s.charAt(i))) {
        return false;
      }
      charSet.add(s.charAt(i));
    }
    return true;
  }

  public boolean isUnique2(String s) {

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FindDuplicatesTest app = new FindDuplicatesTest();

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    boolean result = app.isUnique(s);
    long stop = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(result);

    System.out.println("HashSet Search Time: " + (stop - start));

    start = System.nanoTime();
    result = app.isUnique2(s);
    stop = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(result);

    System.out.println("Array Search Time: " + (stop - start));

  }
}
```

Comment: Is the fact that the characters are sorted relevant? Also, surely we would have the same problem using an integer value, as we would have a duplicate after the first 9 numbers?

Comment: In your example the overhead of initializing a HashSet and inserting elements into it for comparison exceeds the simple array comparison. I don't mean 0-9, I mean arbitrary sequence of say 100,000 numbers and check if a duplicate exists.

Comment: Sorted data can be searched far faster.

Comment: @MadConan i agree, but in my algorithms there would be no difference whether the data was sorted or not

Comment: @DomShahbazi I have added test code to show how on average the HashSet would perform better. But a small dataset like yours with characters a-z is not sufficient to demonstrate performance benefits

Comment: @vsnyc generateRandomString just outputs lots of question marks. Even if we generate a random string, characters will have to repeat after the first 26?

Comment: The question marks you see are because of this line: `Character.toChars(codePoint)`, they are valid character code points but are not english characters or human readable characters. This was just to show a point, the characters will not repeat after first 26. They will definitely repeat after 65536 chars and possibly sooner because of randomness. As I said, integer sequences will be a better test, but if you must use character sequences, you could use something like my test.